# IcedTea plugin not working in Midori web browser

Tags: lubuntu, java, plugins, icedtea, midori

I have Lubuntu 13.04, and I use the Midori WebBrowser. I initially had a problem with the plugins, but later on, I could activate Flash and Java. I use the IcedTea browser plugin to view Java content. This works perfectly fine with Chromium, but it fails to load in Midori. Sometimes, it even says missing plugin for both Flash and Java. In reviews, I have seen it reported that Java works fine in Midori even with IcedTea.

It would be helpful if you could say what the problem is, and help me solve this problem.

EDIT: I have the latest version of java and flash. Also, the website I tested for java, is the java test page in the java website, and also minecraft.net . For flash, it is Youtube.

Comment: In case you don't get the help you need, you can ask at https://answers.launchpad.net/midori but you'll need a Luanchpad account.

Answer (score 1):

I have Lubuntu 13.04 running Oracle Java version 1.7.0_21 and Midori 0.4.3 is working fine to me.

I've just tested at the page:
http://www.java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp

Flash is working fine on Midori too. Flash version is 11.2.202.285. 
I've just tested on YouTube.

I'm using Linux Kernel 3.8.0-23-generic (32-bit).

Are we using the same versions of Midori, Flash and Kernel?

Suggestion: 
Install Oracle Java:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

You can keep IcedTea in case you prefer for some websites/apps. In order to change the java you'll use:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

sources: 
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

If it does not work, pls, add more details such as:

1. what are the java websites that are not working on midori?
2. the same for Adobe Flash. pls?

Cheers,
Iberê

Comment: I have the latest version of java (check edit) and flash. Also, like I have specified, even minecraft.net doesn't work in Midori.